# How to add pseudo element in ::-webkit-scrollbar-button

Tags: html, css, webkit, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a webkit button with linear background along with an icon with the help of ::before element but it does not worked out. Is there any possible way to do the same?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bar2">
        <div class="nav-items">BOOKS</div>
        <div class="nav-items">SONGS</div>
        <div class="nav-items">COOK</div>
        <div class="nav-items">GAMES</div>
        <div class="nav-items">Recents</div>
      </div>
<style>
.bar2{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: overlay;
  background: grey;
}
.nav-items{
  padding:10px;
}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar-track{display: none;}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar{background: transparent; height: 30px;}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement{
  background: url(angle-left.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment{
  background: linear-gradient(to left,white,#00000000);
}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment::before{
  position: absolute;
  background: url(angle-right.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px;
}
.bar2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{display: none;}

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ignore silly corrections(if any). Code edited in mobile.

Comment: Please make your code into a working snippet that we can run.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few unusual things here:

- You likely don't need most of these very specific browser prefixes. Browser prefixes should be a last resort for edge-cases related to a browser or engine.
- There are no buttons in your example, consider using `<a href="#" class="nav-items">BOOKS</a>` tags instead of the `<div>`s you're using. If you're using Javasript use `<button onclick="">` instead. Changing this will get you all the default browser behaviour that is really cumbersome to write yourself (tabindex, keyboard navigation, ...)

But most important for your question:

- When using pseudo elements first thing to set is the `content`. Pseudo elements will not show without it. ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content))

So for the pseudo to work on .`bar2`, something like this should do it:

```
  .bar2::before {
content: ''; 
display: block;
background: red;
min-width: 1rem;
height:1rem;
}
```